# Samsung Gear VR - attach weapon to player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

How can I add gun to player in Gear VR

I tried by adding gun to `OVRCameraRig`, but it dosen't look as I want.

Can any one tell me how I can approach this?

[image]

Comment: You may have to clarify on how you want it to look - what is wrong with the current appearance, and what are you hoping to achieve instead? We'll need more information or else we'll just be guessing at your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

Add the gun to the middle eye, and make the gun always face to forward direction.